# Low Pass Filter for blurring an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, fft

I'm trying to blur an image using fft by passing a low pass filter that I created but the output yields to be an image full of gray noise. I'm just trying to follow the basics here but it seems like there is something wrong with my implementation:

```
from scipy import fftpack
import numpy as np
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image1 = imageio.imread('image.jpg',as_gray=True)

#convert image to numpy array
image1_np=np.array(image)

#fft of image
fft1 = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(image1_np))

#Create a low pass filter image
x,y = image1_np.shape[0],image1_np.shape[1]
#size of circle
e_x,e_y=50,50
#create a box 
bbox=((x/2)-(e_x/2),(y/2)-(e_y/2),(x/2)+(e_x/2),(y/2)+(e_y/2))

low_pass=Image.new("L",(image1_np.shape[0],image1_np.shape[1]),color=0)

draw1=ImageDraw.Draw(low_pass)
draw1.ellipse(bbox, fill=255)

low_pass_np=np.array(low_pass)
low_pass_fft=fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(low_pass))

#multiply both the images
filtered=np.multiply(fft1,low_pass_fft)

#inverse fft
ifft2 = abs(fftpack.ifft2(fftpack.ifftshift(filtered)))

#save the image
imageio.imsave('fft-then-ifft.png', ifft2.astype(np .uint8))
```

[image: Original Image:]

[image: Low Pass filter created]

[image: Resultant Image]

Comment: Your low-pass filter is designed in the frequency domain, you shouldn't apply FFT to it. The output of the inverse FFT, you should take the real part, not the magnitude (`abs`). If the imaginary component is more than numerical imprecision (values in the order of 1e-12 or so), it means something is wrong with the filter definition.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to extract just the real part while taking the inverse fft in python? I tried using np.real(np.fft.ifft2(filtered)) but it still yields a image with gray noise.

Comment: You other issue is that your frequency-domain filter is it normalize. Draw it with values of 1, then the filter output will have the same scaling as the input. What you’re seeing is hopefully caused by that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo), there are a few things that need to be corrected:

- The provided elliptical shape for the low-pass filter makes sense in the frequency-domain, so you shouldn't be computing its FFT.
- The filter magnitude of `255` scales the results by the same amount. As you store such large values, the `uint8` type wraps around to keep only the 8 least significant bits, resulting in something that looks like noise. This can be fixed by simply changing the value of the filter:

  ```
  draw1.ellipse(bbox, fill=1)
  ```
- After readjusting the scaling, there computed `filtered` may still get slightly out of the desired 0-255 range in some areas of the image. This creates wrap-around spots (black areas in regions surrounded by white pixels, white areas in regions surrounded by black pixels, or even gradient bands where the image goes from white to black to white). To avoid this is common to clip the values to the 0-255 range with the following:

  ```
  ifft2 = np.real(fftpack.ifft2(fftpack.ifftshift(filtered)))
  ifft2 = np.maximum(0, np.minimum(ifft2, 255))
  ```

After making these corrections, you should have the following code:

```
from scipy import fftpack
import numpy as np
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image1 = imageio.imread('image.jpg',as_gray=True)

#convert image to numpy array
image1_np=np.array(image1)

#fft of image
fft1 = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(image1_np))

#Create a low pass filter image
x,y = image1_np.shape[0],image1_np.shape[1]
#size of circle
e_x,e_y=50,50
#create a box 
bbox=((x/2)-(e_x/2),(y/2)-(e_y/2),(x/2)+(e_x/2),(y/2)+(e_y/2))

low_pass=Image.new("L",(image1_np.shape[0],image1_np.shape[1]),color=0)

draw1=ImageDraw.Draw(low_pass)
draw1.ellipse(bbox, fill=1)

low_pass_np=np.array(low_pass)

#multiply both the images
filtered=np.multiply(fft1,low_pass_np)

#inverse fft
ifft2 = np.real(fftpack.ifft2(fftpack.ifftshift(filtered)))
ifft2 = np.maximum(0, np.minimum(ifft2, 255))

#save the image
imageio.imsave('fft-then-ifft.png', ifft2.astype(np .uint8))
```

And the following filtered image:

[image]